# How to prove that predicate is expressible?

Tags: group-theory, logic, predicate-logic

I have to prove, that predicate "x is transposition" in $S_5$ group. I can use such symbols, as `*, 1, -1, =`. However, I don't know any algorithm or way, which can to prove this statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Andre Nicolas has deleted his answer, but you I think you could do this as $x*x=1$, $x \ne 1$, and there exists $y$ such that $y*y*y=1$, $y \ne 1$, and $x*y=y*x$.

Comment: thank you for your help. You are very cool :)